# クローラーにブログのカテゴリーを伝えるには？

Tags: javascript, html

雑記ブログなのでクローラーにカテゴリーを伝えたいです。
自分で調べて下記のように認識したのですが正しいか教えていただければ幸いです。

マイクロデータで行う方法を見つけたので、こちらで実装したいです。

私のサイトの例
http://example.com/index.html 
[http://example.com/html/SEOクイズ1.html](http://example.com/html/SEO%E3%82%AF%E3%82%A4%E3%82%BA1.html)（1から10まで、ページがある） 
[http://example.com/html/アフィリエイトクイズ1.html](http://example.com/html/%E3%82%A2%E3%83%95%E3%82%A3%E3%83%AA%E3%82%A8%E3%82%A4%E3%83%88%E3%82%AF%E3%82%A4%E3%82%BA1.html)（1から10まで、ページがある）

このようになっているので、フォルダ名でカテゴリーを伝えることは難しいです。

よって、下記のようにbody終了上あたりに記載すれば、フォルダ分けしなくても、
ちゃんとクローラーにカテゴリーが伝わるか教えていただけますでしょうか？
人間には無関係の情報なので、最後に記載したいと思っています。

アフィリエイトクイズ2.htmlページに記載する情報
（トップ＞クイズ＞アフィリエイトクイズ＞アフィリエイトクイズ2）
（トップ＞クイズ＞アフィリエイトクイズ2の方が良いでしょうか？）

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "BreadcrumbList",
  "itemListElement":
  [
    {
      "@type": "ListItem",
      "position": 1,
      "item":
      {
        "@id": "https://example.com/index.html",
        "name": "トップページ"
      }
    },
    {
      "@type": "ListItem",
      "position": 2,
      "item":
      {
        "@id": "https://example.com/html/SEOクイズ1.html",
        "name": "クイズ"
      }
    },
    {
      "@type": "ListItem",
      "position": 3,
      "item":
      {
        "@id": "https://example.com/html/アフィリエイトクイズ1.html",
        "name": "アフィリエイトクイズ"
      }
    },
    {
      "@type": "ListItem",
      "position": 4,
      "item":
      {
        "@id": "https://example.com/html/アフィリエイトクイズ2.html",
        "name": "アフィリエイトクイズ"
      }
    }
  ]
}
</script>
```

SEOクイズ2.htmlページに記載する情報
（トップ＞クイズ＞SEOクイズ＞SEOクイズ2）
（トップ＞クイズ＞SEOクイズ2の方が良いでしょうか？）

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "BreadcrumbList",
  "itemListElement":
  [
    {
      "@type": "ListItem",
      "position": 1,
      "item":
      {
        "@id": "https://example.com/index.html",
        "name": "トップページ"
      }
    },
    {
      "@type": "ListItem",
      "position": 2,
      "item":
      {
        "@id": "https://example.com/html/SEOクイズ1.html",
        "name": "クイズ"
      }
    },
    {
      "@type": "ListItem",
      "position": 3,
      "item":
      {
        "@id": "https://example.com/html/SEOクイズ2.html",
        "name": "SEOクイズ"
      }
    }
  ]
}
</script>
```

これで大丈夫でしょうか？

最後にうまく認識されているかを確認する方法はおそらくないのですよね。
これをやって数日後に順位が上がれば認識されたと判断するしかないでしょうね。

プログラミングの質問か微妙ですが、seoというタグがないのでhtmlを付けました。

お忙しいところ恐縮ですが教えていただければ幸いです。

Comment: 記述された内容はあくまでサイトの構造を示す [パンくずリスト](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/breadcrumb?hl=ja) を示す為のものであり、SEO視点でのカテゴリーを伝えるのとは違うような気がします (そもそもクローラーにブログのカテゴリーを伝える方法があるのかを私は知りませんが)。

Comment: わかりました。そしてソースコードは正しいでしょうか？

Comment: やりたいことに合致するのはmeta要素の`keywords`であるように思います（そして、それは現在SEOに効果がないと言われています）。